Преобразовать объект в функцию, которая возвращает этот объект
Имеется объект:
var abc = {a: 123};

Необходимо преобразовать его в функцию, которая будет возвращать данный объект. Делаю так:
abc = () => abc;

Вывожу abc() в консоль, но вместо {a: 123} в консоли - () => abc. Почему и можно ли это исправить?

Потому что abc стал указывать не на объект, а на функцию

@andreymal, это ясно, но почему () => abc <= сюда не передаётся значение переменной?

Функция возвращает значение переменной abc, а в вашем случае значением переменной abc является функция

А то, что вы хотите, делается например как-то так abc = ((xyz) => () => xyz)(abc) — функция возвращает функцию, которая возвращает значение переменной xyz, а так как значение переменной xyz никто нигде не меняет, то в ней так и остаётся лежать объект

@andreymal, да, спасибо за разъяснения - всё так и оказалось.

Ты творишь какую-то дичь, тем не менее, держи:


var abc = {a: 123}
abc = (abc => () => abc)(abc)
console.log(abc())



